# Comparator -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare numbers from an array using this other method. I am not sure how it's called but it's this:

```
template<typename T>
using Comparator = bool(*)(T, T);
```

My code gets build, but when i started it, it crashes on this line:

```
if(comp(arr[i], arr[i+1])){
```

with error message:     -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

what am I doing wrong and what is the name of this method for comparing values ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
using Comparator = bool(*)(T, T);

template<typename T>
void theHell(T arr[], int len, Comparator<T> comp){

for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
    if(comp(arr[i], arr[i+1])){
        cout << "pice of code" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 3 ,3 ,4, 4, 67, 5, 32, 4};
    Comparator<int> comp;
    int len = sizeof(arr);
    theHell(arr, len, comp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you just declare comp but do not implement it

Comment: "what is the name of this method for comparing values" usually either called a comparator, a functor, or a predicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comparator<int>` is a function pointer type that takes 2 `int`s and returns a `bool`.

That means that `comp` is a pointer to a function. What function? You haven't told it what function to use. You need to point it at a function like so:

```
bool compare_func(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
...
int main() {
   Comparator<int> comp = compare_func;
```

Comment: I manually changed the len variable to    "   int len = 8;  " and still doesn't help

Comment: @murloc my answer doesn't refer to your incorrect length argument

Comment: Thank you, it worked.  I will give you credit in a second. Can this be quilifed as a high- order function ?

Comment: Yes you can consider `theHell` as such because it takes in a function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> what am I doing wrong

`comp` is an *uninitialized* function pointer, it's obvious that you get a crash when calling it inside the template.

Also, you are passing the array length in bytes (as returned by `sizeof`), while your function expects a number of elements.

> and what is the name of this method for comparing values ?

"access violation", I guess.

---

To fix your code, you have to write a  comparison function compatible with the function signature of your function pointer, and use it to initialize `comp`; also, fix the initialization of `n` by dividing it by `sizeof(int)`.

---

Incidentally, generic functions usually accept a more general parameter for comparison functions, so to allow the library user to pass any callable (be it a function, a functor, a lambda, an `std::function`, ...) to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

**First:**

```
int len = sizeof(arr);
```

This line will give you teh size of the array * the size of the `int` in you platform. You just need the size of your array. So, you should divide it by the size of `int`:

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

**Second:**

Your comeratror has no defnetion. However, it may be better if you use `std::function` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void theHell(T arr[], int len, std::function<bool(int,int)> comp){
for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
    if(comp(arr[i], arr[i+1])){
        cout << "pice of code" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 3 ,3 ,4, 4, 67, 5, 32, 4};
    auto comp=[](auto a,auto b){return a<b;};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    theHell(arr, len, comp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` gives you the array size **in bytes**. theHell() is called with a len of 36 (9 ints á 4 byte) instead of 9 so you get a memory access violation error when accessing arr[10] in theHell().

To get the number of elements you have to use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: I manually changed the len variable to    "   int len = 8;  " and still doesn't help

Comment: it is 9 by the way